# How do I implement a block suggesting other relevant content?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I want to put a block in the left column on my products page, to suggest similar products. Can I do this with a block based on the "search API" module? Does this module allow to propose products in a block, similar to the viewed page?

Comment: What criteria will you use for similarity?

Comment: I just do not know. I wish the block search api compare product page currently visited with all the product pages and show you the similar page pertinence in the block. But I do not know if that's possible.

A second option could be to create a keyword field on all product pages and to enter several keyword compare the keyword of the visited page and those of other pages and display the most relevant in the block.

I do not speak English so I do not know if my question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Similar Entries](https://www.drupal.org/project/similar) module for this.

> Similar Entries provides lists of links to site content related to the current node being viewed. Links can be displayed in standard blocks or as part of custom views.